# How to use different condition's in np.where

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm using the below code which generates a new column called **Category** but it is not generating the correct output which i'm looking for.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

Order = pd.read_excel (r"C:\Sample.xls", sheet_name='Orders')
Return = pd.read_excel (r"C:\Sample.xls", sheet_name='Returns')

Order['Category'] = np.where(Order['Sales']>10000, 'High', 
                        np.where((Order['Sales']>5000) & (Order['Sales']<9999), 'Medium',
                          'Low'))
Order.merge(Return, on='Order ID', how='inner')\
    .groupby(['State','Category']).agg(Sales=("Sales", sum)).reset_index()
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

**REQUIRED OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: It looks for first look good, can you be more specific with problem?

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use np.where() ? I can see you are already using pandas and you can use simpler way to filter dataframes.

Comment: @SAL requirement is to use only np.where().

Comment: @jezrael the **Category** from the **OUTPUT** is giving me only **LOW** but if you check my **REQUIRED OUTPUT** based on the condition it has been categorized.

Comment: What is `print (Order['Sales'].dtype)` ?

Comment: @jezrael it is **float64**

Comment: hmmm, is possible convert values of `OUTPUT` to text?

Comment: look into [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html)

Comment: and [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) instead of nested `np.where`?

Answer (score 0):

Go through your Sales column and add as much as condition (if condition) you want.

```
for i,e in enumerate(df['Sales']):
  if e < 30:
    df.at[i,'Category'] = 'low'
```